# Paramaters of $scope.function becomes undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have this html

```
<div ng-controller = "RetrieveCtrl as retrieve" >
    <form>
        <input ng-model = "retrieve.input1">
        <input ng-model = "retrieve.input2">

        <button type="submit" ng-click="retrieve.retrieveEntry()">Search</button>
.
.
.
```

with this controller

```
app.controller('RetrieveCtrl', ['$scope' , '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.retrieveEntry = function () {

        var input1 = $scope.retrieve.input1;
        var input2 = $scope.retrieve.input2;

        // validate input1 & input2 first...
        // input1 & input2 part of URL

        $http.get(...


        )

    };

}
```

which is working fine, I was able to retrieve my data from the web service. What I want to do is to refactor the function into two:

```
app.controller('RetrieveCtrl', ['$scope' , '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.clickSearch = function() {

        var input1 = $scope.retrieve.input1;
        var input2 = $scope.retrieve.input2;

        // validate input1 & input2 first...
        $scope.retrieveEntry(input1, input2);

    };

    $scope.retrieveEntry = function (a, b) {


        // build a and b in URL
        $http.get(...


        )

    };

}
```

so that I could reuse `$scope.retrieveEntry` on other functionalities. However, a and b becomes undefined, after I split the function into two (button's `ng-click` is updated to `"retrieve.clickSearch()"`). I suspect it has to do with `$scope`, which I don't have much clear understanding of what's going on (I'm still quite confused with this and `$scope`) Could someone explain what's happening behind and how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this would solve your issue, but you are not making correct use of controller as syntax. You controller implementation should look something like this:

```
app.controller('RetrieveCtrl', ['$scope' , '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var self=this;
    self.clickSearch = function() {
        // validate input1 & input2 first...
        self.retrieveEntry(self.input1, self.input2);

    };

    self.retrieveEntry = function (a, b) {


        // build a and b in URL
        $http.get(...


        )

    };

}
```

Once you start using controller as syntax you mostly add functionality to your controller not scope directly.

Comment: I actually more in favor of using `this` (or self) as I'm seeing this on newer code examples and it works for me often. However, I'm constrained to use `$scope` (I see this on older examples of angularjs), for the sake of consistency with the codes of my colleagues, most of them use `$scope`. I can't justify now the use of `this` as I myself am not yet very clear on `this` and `$scope`(and can't explain very well to them) and besides, we already have a codebase to work on.

Comment: The code you have shown, adds the function to scope directly, whereas the functions in view are referenced using `retrieve`. Is that a typo.

Comment: That's not a typo error and it's working (my co-worker did that). That's syntactic sugar (I call that alias), right? Is it incorrect/bad practice to attach functions directly to `$scope`? From what I read, `this` and `$scope` may or may not be the same but my understanding is still muddled. Using `this` or `self` works always for me, and your solution indeed worked.